# Check String Array for ENTER presses?

Tags: java

```
do{
    input.nextLine();
    linhas [nLinhas] = input.nextLine();
    nLinhas++;
}
while ();
```

I have this inside a switch which is inside a do-while (menu). I am doing a text editor, in which I ask the user for input, and in this part I'm trying to store the input in "String [] linhas".

> ```
> (Portuguese) | (English)
> Linhas = Lines 
> nLinhas = Number of Lines
> ```

The two nextLine() is because of a previous next().charAt().

The program should keep asking for more input unless the user presses ENTER two times... How do I go about doing this? I've tried using .length, .contains, but nothing worked...

Comment: Two times in a row or total ?

Comment: in a row I daresay @OrelEraki. since this works with `newLine()` for input reading...

Comment: @OrelEraki two times in a row :) Basically, I was thinking of using contains, and checking the number of lines for the number of lines + 1, for the presence of ""...

Comment: Didn't you ask that same question yesterday?

Comment: enter two times, with no content => 2 lines blank. simple test

Comment: @Jan yes, I did, but I didn't find a solution. I do think this one is much better explained though... I also tried deleting the previous question, but it didn't work... :/

Comment: You could've edited yesterdays question. Now those who spent time on helping you yesterday feel you don't value their efforts and just try again.

Answer (score 0):

This works will take multiple "enter" keystrokes:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String readString = scanner.nextLine();
while(readString!=null) {
    System.out.println(readString);

    if (readString.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Read Enter Key.");
    }

    if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        readString = scanner.nextLine();
    } else {
        readString = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `KeyListener` and checking when the user hits Enter?  Store a variable for space bar presses in a row, and if that number hits 2, perform an action.

Answer (score 0):

This will be one solution

```
do {
    String inputLine = input.nextLine();
    linhas [nLinhas] = inputLine;
    if (nLinhas > 1 && linhas[nLinhas].equals("") && linhas[nLinhas-1].equals("")) {
        break;
    }
    nLinhas++;
}
while (true);
```

Comment: "Incompatible operand types"... :S String and Int...

Comment: Code Updated, Accidentally putted `== 0` instead of "" code fixed.

Comment: I did that, but it's not working either... :/

Comment: @Martins2759, Have not wrote Java for a while now, fixed it. (Used `var`)

Comment: @Martins2759, Also fixed the `.equals` part.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean hasNotEnd=true;

    while(hasNotEnd) {
        System.out.println("read 1st input0");
        String readString1 = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("read 2nd input0");
        String readString2 = scanner.nextLine();

        if(readString1.isEmpty() && readString2.isEmpty()){
            hasNotEnd=false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
    String inputString;
    inputString=input.nextLine();
    linhas [nLinhas] = inputString;
    if(nLinhas > 0 && linhas [nLinhas-1].equals("") && linhas [nLinhas].equals("")){
        break;
    }
    nLinhas++;

}
while (true);
```

Comment: Do I need to always nextLine to a string and only then put the string in the linhas [nLinhas]? :S

Comment: no, is not necesary you can put either `linhas [nLinhas]=input.nextLine();`